# Lost display of multibyte utf-8 characters since changed to 64-bit OS

Tags: linux, 64-bit

I switched to the 64-bit version of Arch Linux after they ended support for the 32 bit version. Since then all multibyte UTF-8 characters display as a dotted outline rectangle, regardless of the app concerned (but as I do everything in xterms, this is probably an `xterm` problem). The actual hex value of each such character remains correct, just the appearance is lost. Suggestions as to how to restore them?

My `.Xdefaults` is

```
# XTerm*metaSendsEscape: true
XTerm*metaSendsEscape: false
XTerm*visualBell: true
XTerm*background: black
XTerm*foreground: white

# pointerShape Options: XTerm, left_ptr, bogosity, arrow, pirate, gumby
XTerm*pointerShape: left_ptr

# XTerm*pointerColor: red
XTerm*pointerColorBackground: white

#  makes left double clicks highlight full path names, IP addresses 
#XTerm*charClass:  33:48,37:48,43:48,45-47:48,64:48,126:48,95:48
xterm*borderWidth: 0

# turns off accented (8 bit) characters
XTerm*eightBitInput: false
XTerm*selectToClipboard: true
```

Answer (score 1):

When I need another xterm, I generate it thru fluxbox with a hotkey command, which works fine and is real quick but sends any error messages into /dev/null

But when I started an xterm at the command line in the traditional way, it gave me these warnings

```
~ $ xterm: cannot load font "-Misc-Fixed-medium-R-*-*-13-120-75-75-C-120-ISO10646-1"
xterm: cannot load font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1"
```

I tracked them down to https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs-fonts.html
which includes http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/download/ucs-fonts.tar.gz in its Downloads section.

Then followed the install instructions in README.